# Phone Identity with Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I'm looking to build some C# desktop client application that will send out a large number of PDF to sign to a large number of different individual so I'm wondering if the docusign API provide access to automate the Phone identity feature? I was not able to find out the page on their site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can access this through the api, the DocuSign Developer Center has pages on the more prevalent features, for full information always check the documentation:

[DocuSign API Documentation](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation)

You can add a recipient parameter in your request body that sets the `idCheckConfigurationName` which can be used for an RSA ID check or SMS authentication, and there's also a `phoneAuthentication` setting which I believe is what you are looking for.  The JSON would look something like:

```
"recipients": { 
     "signers": [{
        "idCheckConfigurationName": "string1",
        "phoneAuthentication": "string2"
     }]
}
```

where `string1` could be `ID Check $` for an RSA ID Check or `SMS Auth $` for SMS auth for instance, and `string2` is actually made up of a boolean and a list which are used to configure the phone authentication.  Please see DocuSign's documentation for more info.

Answer (score 1):

To specify phone authentication for a recipient, you need to specify the following properties for the recipient in the **Create Envelope** request:

```
   "idCheckConfigurationName": "Phone Auth $",
   "requireIdLookup": "true",
   "phoneAuthentication": {
       "recipMayProvideNumber": "false",
       "senderProvidedNumbers": [
           "206-222-1111"
       ]
   }
```

For example, here's a **Create Envelope** request that specifies phone authentication for the first (and only) recipient.

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes

{
   "status" : "sent",
   "emailBlurb":"Test Email Body",
   "emailSubject": "-- Test Email Subject --",
   "recipients": {
       "signers" : [
       {
           "email": "bobsemail@outlook.com",
           "name": "Bob Adamson",
           "idCheckConfigurationName": "Phone Auth $",
           "requireIdLookup": "true",
           "phoneAuthentication": {
               "recipMayProvideNumber": "false",
               "senderProvidedNumbers": [
                   "206-111-2222"
               ]
           },
           "recipientId": "1",
           "routingOrder": "1",
           "tabs": {
               "signHereTabs": [
               {
                   "recipientId": "1",
                   "tabLabel": "Customer_Signature",
                   "documentId": "1",
                   "pageNumber": "1",
                   "xPosition": "99",
                   "yPosition": "424"
               }],
               "dateSignedTabs": [
               {
                   "recipientId": "1",
                   "tabLabel": "Customer_Date",
                   "documentId": "1",
                   "pageNumber": "1",
                   "xPosition": "373",
                   "yPosition": "456"
               }]
             }
        }]
    },
   "documents": [
    {
       "name": "TestDocAPI.pdf",
       "documentId": 1,
       "documentBase64": "BASE_64_ENCODED_DOCUMENT_BYTE_STREAM"
    }]
}
```

This is just one example -- the properties you set under the **phoneAuthentication** object may differ depending on your specific requirements. See the DocuSign REST API Guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) for information about additional properties available under **phoneAuthentication**.