# Phone Authetication using DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

How to implement Phone Authetication using DocuSign API. Is Phone Authentication is available in demo account or it is available in paid account only?

Answer (score 0):

Phone Authentication should be enabled (and free) in the DocuSign demo environment. For details about how to specify Phone Authentication for an envelope recipient, see the second answer in this other post: [Phone Identity with Docusign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448765/phone-identity-with-docusign).